# Get the values from JSON document

Tags: javascript, json

I have the following JSON document,

```
var data = [
  {"id":1, "username":"user1"},
  {"id":2, "username":"user2"},
  {"id":3, "username":"user3"}
]
```

How to get all the values with the key "username", without using any loop?

Comment: What is your language ?

Comment: @Gearnode: The language is javascript, but i dont want to use any loop

Comment: @Krisalay, Please check the answer . Hope you are looking for the same solution..`values with the key "username", without using any loop`.

Comment: @RohitJindal yeah your solution works, but this solution is not without using loop, in fact it is using the loop internally

Comment: @RohitJindal got it.Thanks

Comment: Please educate yourself on the meaning of the term "JSON". This is not a JSON object (actually, there is no such thing as a "JSON object"). Also, why do you not want to use a loop, and what do you mean by "using any loop"? Any logic to go through the array and find certain elements will by definition use a loop in one way or another.

Comment: The only alternative to using a loop is to use recursion. Is that the kind of solution you were looking for?

Comment: Nor is it a "JSON document". Neither I nor any else knows what that means. You must have meant "JavaScript object" or "JavaScript array".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make this in ES6/5

```
data.map(function(element) {
  return element.username;
});
```

[Documentation here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Or without loop

```
data[0].username
data[1].username
...
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try this it will work:**

```
var data = [
  {"id":1, "username":"user1"},
  {"id":2, "username":"user2"},
  {"id":3, "username":"user3"}
];

var propUsername = data.map(function(elem) {
  return {username:elem.username};
});

console.log(propUsername);
```

Output:

[image]

**Working fiddle:**

https://jsfiddle.net/kgpumk4r/

Difference between `forloop` and `map`:

- loop iterates over a list and applies some operation with side effects to each list member (such as saving each one to the database for example)
- map iterates over a list, transforms each member of that list, and returns another list of the same size with the transformed members (such as get single property from each object)

Hence, We can prefer `map` over `foreach` loop as execution will be fast with `map`.

Comment: What is `forloop`? Also, there is little to no performance difference between `map` and `forEach`.

Answer (score 0):

```
data[0][username];
data[1][username];
data[2][username];
```

Comment: what if i have 200 elements in my json array?

Comment: Then you have to use loop.

Comment: is there a way to do that, without using any loop?

Comment: No. If you know which value are you looking for, e.g. "user2", and don't know which element it is, you have to use loop till you find the element.

Comment: If you need to use a loop, then your answer must show how to use a loop.